# Create folder in salesforce using Metadata

Tags: apex, metadata-api, folder

How to create folder using Matadata in documents in Salesforce.

```
public static MetadataService.MetadataPort createService(String session, String instance)
    {

        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        service.timeout_x = 120000;
        service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = session == null ? UserInfo.getSessionId(): session;
        service.setEndpoint_x(instance);      
        return service; 
    } 

public void CreateNewFolder()
    {
        MetadataService.Folder doc = new MetadataService.Folder(); 
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        service = createService(UserInfo.getSessionId(),URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm());
        List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results = new List<MetadataService.SaveResult>();
        results = service.createMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] { doc });
}
```

> Error-Save error: Initial expression is of incorrect type, expected:
>   MetadataService.Metadata

Comment: Had you fixed the error? If so, please let me know how you fixed